# helm chart upgrade with same images stored in a different location

Tags: kubernetes-helm, docker-registry

I have deployed a chart that refers images
image: a/b/myImage:tag
i copy the image to a new location x/y/myImage:tag (same registry) , update the chart then perform an helm upgrade while my application is running

Will the pod be restarted ? or is helm/kubernetes smart enough to record the new image location without pod restart since it is same image.

new location would be only used in case of pod crash or application stop and go

Brs
Thanks for your support

Comment: The pod will be restarted since the hash from the content of the manifest will be different.

Answer (score 0):

The pod will be restarted.

If you want your service to be available all the time, you can try to deploy a multi-copy application through statefulset, it can guarantee an orderly restart。

[k8s/StatefulSet](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/statefulset/)